# Array has only 4 elements but it shows like it has 5 elements even after removing empty elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array with 4 elements and in one scenario I want to pop one element from the array. But after pop array gives the same result as before. 
I have checked in the console window and there I have find a different behavior like array length is 4 and it shows like it has 5 elements. 
[image]

I have tried to remove the empty elements also but still the same issue is coming .

```
var brudcrumbDataArray=JSON.parse(brudcrumbDataString);

            brudcrumbDataArray = brudcrumbDataArray.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 
            console.log(brudcrumbDataArray)
            brudcrumbDataArray.pop();
            console.log(brudcrumbDataArray)
```

Her is the array :

```
[{"name":"Dashboard","url":"","path":"","class":"icon-home2 position-left","type":"MainMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Main","url":"#/dashboard","path":"/dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Sub Accounts","url":"#/account/customers","path":"/account/customers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"End Users","url":"#/account/endusers","path":"/account/endusers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Profile","url":"#/user-dashboard","path":"/user-dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""}]
```

After pop also array gives the same data and same length. Can someone help me to solve this issue ?

Snippet, check your console to see the problem:

```js
var brudcrumbDataString =`[{"name":"Dashboard","url":"","path":"","class":"icon-home2 position-left","type":"MainMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Main","url":"#/dashboard","path":"/dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Sub Accounts","url":"#/account/customers","path":"/account/customers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"End Users","url":"#/account/endusers","path":"/account/endusers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Profile","url":"#/user-dashboard","path":"/user-dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""}]`;

var brudcrumbDataArray=JSON.parse(brudcrumbDataString);

brudcrumbDataArray = brudcrumbDataArray.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 
console.log(brudcrumbDataArray)
brudcrumbDataArray.pop();
console.log(brudcrumbDataArray)
```

Comment: any samples of input output?

Comment: @zabusa sample is there in the image , I can provide you if you need as text

Comment: i think you are referencing it with the same object.thats why it shows 4.try a diffrent variable name

Comment: Can you add the `brudcrumbDataString` string? So we can play with it

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV change the variable names.make it immutable objects.

Comment: Can u provide jsfiddle to check it with u?

Comment: They are same instance of array that is why console.log shows like this. Side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A result on the console seems to be correct. Both the logs on the console window are showing the result after the operation. **Why is the first log showing a result in it?** because, in javascript, complex objects get stored by reference, that's why your first log does show a result in it too.

*Store by reference? what does it mean? : https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch04_04.htm*

Try below one,

```
var brudcrumbDataString =`[{"name":"Dashboard","url":"","path":"","class":"icon-home2 position-left","type":"MainMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Main","url":"#/dashboard","path":"/dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Sub Accounts","url":"#/account/customers","path":"/account/customers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"End Users","url":"#/account/endusers","path":"/account/endusers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Profile","url":"#/user-dashboard","path":"/user-dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""}]`;

var brudcrumbDataArray=JSON.parse(brudcrumbDataString);

brudcrumbDataArray = brudcrumbDataArray.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(brudcrumbDataArray)))
brudcrumbDataArray.pop();
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(brudcrumbDataArray)))
```

Look closely here, we are doing deep data copy with using JSON operations, by surrounding object in `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(  ))` and it won't point to reference anymore now.

And log will be more clear as below,

[image]

Comment: Great answer, But still I have a doubt . do the console.log change if we change the reference after the console.log line ??

Comment: I would say this is a bug in a browser. execute your same code in simple nodejs environment and you would see intended output there. 

try this one in browser. 1) create one array; arr = [1,2,3,4,5]    2) do "console.log(arr)". dont open the log, keep it in closed state.    3) change value from array; "a[0] = 100"    4) now expand previous log, performed in #2 and notice that value is updated

Answer (score -1):

it showing because the reference to the same `object` so when you `pop` last element the object get modified and shows the length as `4` so the first consoled object also get updated.

```js
var brudcrumbDataArray = [{"name":"Dashboard","url":"","path":"","class":"icon-home2 position-left","type":"MainMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Main","url":"#/dashboard","path":"/dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Sub Accounts","url":"#/account/customers","path":"/account/customers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"End Users","url":"#/account/endusers","path":"/account/endusers","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""},{"name":"Profile","url":"#/user-dashboard","path":"/user-dashboard","class":"","type":"SubMenu","queryParams":""}]


//var brudcrumbDataArray=JSON.parse(brudcrumbDataString);

            var newBrudcrumbDataArray = brudcrumbDataArray.filter(function(n){ return n != undefined }); 
            console.log(brudcrumbDataArray)
            newBrudcrumbDataArray.pop();
            console.log(newBrudcrumbDataArray)
```

Comment: let me check with your solution

Comment: now after pop() last element got popped from the array(+1 for that ), but still the length and array element mismatch is there

Comment: can you please check the image i have posted in the question. My doubt is why it is showing 5 elements even if it has array length 4. As per my understanding if an array has some empty elements then length will  include that too , length simply gives the last items index + 1 , so here if we have 5 elements then it should give length 5 not 4. That part i am confused about

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV it because you are referencing the same object right?so the array get updated and its length too..but the 5 is showing its already consoled value.but the array get updated

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV the referencing objects get changed because its an mutable object right?

Comment: but that change is happens only after first console.log. so before the change happens the console prints the array . and it shows 5 elements like (5)[{}{}{}{}{}] and shows length of 4 is what i m not getting

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV it only happen for first for the second one the element already got poped out right.your are consoling it after the `pop` functionality

Comment: and how the consoled data get updated ? you have mentioned in the answer like first consoled data will get updated after changing the value , but how ?

Comment: I have two consoles one is before pop and one is after pop . issue is in the first one i mean the one before pop . And even if i remove the pop then also it is showing like 5 elements and length 4

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV you are referencing the same object right.the object gets updated but the (5) not getting updated thats chrome already rendered thats why.but variable is updated.beacuse its in the memeory.and same reference get updated in javascript.because array is mutable